# Windows Server Scheduled Drive Optimization (defrag/TRIM) drives list is empty

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, windows-server, defragment, trim

I want to setup scheduled drives optimization on Windows Server 2019 (defrag HDDs and TRIM SSDs).

The Optimize Drives main window lists my drives properly. But when I want to select the drives that I want to optimize on a scheduled basis then this list is empty - see screenshots.

Why is the second list empty (for scheduled optimization) but drives are normally detected in the main Optimize Drives window? The popup says `Only drives that can be scheduled for automatic optimization are shown`. One of my disk is a M.2 SSD connected directly to the server motherboard, the other ones are a mix of HDDs and SSDs within an external disk shelf and connected to the server using a LSI HBA card.

[image: Optimize Drives]

[image: Optimize Drives]

PS 1: All disks are NTFS

PS 2: When I click "Turn on" then the second window appears allowing me to enable and opening the third window with the empty list of drives.

Comment: `I want to setup scheduled drives optimization` Why?

Comment: @Gantendo Because yesterday I accidentally run this tool and saw one of my 16TB disk was like 30% fragmented and the defrag process took more than 48 hours (other HDD also needed defrag). I want to automatically defrag my drives instead of manually checking if they need optimization.

Comment: What file systems on those drives?

Comment: @JoepvanSteen All NTFS

Comment: What happens when you click "Turn On"?  [Edit] your question instead of submitting a temporary comment.

Comment: You will have to use third-party software to defrag those drives, in all likelihood, the reason the disks are not listed is due to the HBA card.

Comment: @Ramhound But then why my M.2 SSD connected directly to the motherboard isn't listed?

Comment: @Darxis - SSDs are optimized not defragged.  In your screenshot you have a HDD selected when you pressed 'Turn On'.  SSDs are not affected by file fragmentation.

Comment: @Ramhound Yes, that's why this tool is called Optimize Drives and not Defragment Drives, it TRIMs SSDs and defrag HDDs. I should be able to schedule SSDs for TRIM and HDDs for defrag but none of my drives are listed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151749/discussion-between-darxis-and-ramhound).